# How does repair work?

Tags: leviathan-warships

I know that you can repair your ship at a repair buoy, but I've also noticed that upon taking sufficient damage (like 75% of health) some ships appear to slowly regenerate some of the damage taken. How exactly does this repair system work?

Comment: It's worth noting that repair buoys have a certain amount of charge (the yellow line), they will recharge, but only if there are no ships in their repair radius.